# Force ESRI Silverlight Navigation control to adhere to tile cache zoom levels?

Tags: silverlight, arcgis-silverlight-api

Is it possible to force the Silverlight Navigation control to stick to the zoom levels associated with a particular tiled map service? The map tiles don't look very good when the images are being stretched by Silverlight to a zoom level they were not intended for. Labels are hard to read, etc.

This doesn't look so good:

[image]

This is a little better:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `SnapToLevels` property of the Map control.

> SnapToLevels is off by default and will allow you to zoom to any ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map.Resolution. Tiled layers will automatically interpolate images when displaying layers at resolutions in between levels.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map~SnapToLevels.html

Answer (score 0):

In ArcEngine there's something called DetailsThreshold, if you set it to 0, it will always retrieve the lower zoom level tiles, maybe there's a similar for Silverlight.